# Numerical integration error using Scipy.integrate

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to carry out the following integration. The code starts giving error when the value of k exceeds 4 and the value of Tc exceeds 300. The error message is shown at the bottom of the code. I carried out some trials and found that the multipliers 2 and 0.5 in the statements below respectively are creating some error. Was looking for a fix for this issue.

```py
B = (2 * (Ro ** 2 - ((Ro - a) ** 2))) ** 0.5
return [0, ((a - Ro) + ((Ro ** 2 - 0.5 * (z ** 2))) ** 0.5)]
```

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import nquad

Ro = 0.01
rat = 1
Ess = 207.8e9
k = 10
Tc = 900
Tm = 300

Ri = 0
a = rat * Ro

B = (2 * (Ro ** 2 - ((Ro - a) ** 2))) ** 0.5


def Cc55(y, z):
    R = (y ** 2 + z ** 2) ** 0.5
    Kc = 1.7 * (1 + 1.276 * (10 ** (-4)) * Tc + 6.648 * (10 ** (-8)) * (Tc ** 2))
    Km = 15.379 * (
        1
        - 1.264 * (10 ** (-3)) * Tm
        + 2.092 * (10 ** (-6)) * (Tm ** 2)
        - 7.223 * (10 ** (-10)) * (Tm ** 3)
    )
    a = (Kc - Km) / Km
    C = (
        1
        - (a / (k + 1))
        + (a ** 2 / (2 * k + 1))
        - (a ** 3 / (3 * k + 1))
        + (a ** 4 / (4 * k + 1))
        - (a ** 5 / (5 * k + 1))
    )
    d1 = (R - Ri) / (Ro - Ri)
    D = (
        d1
        - ((a * (d1 ** (k + 1))) / (k + 1))
        + (((a ** 2) * (d1 ** (2 * k + 1))) / ((2 * k) + 1))
        - (((a ** 3) * (d1 ** (3 * k + 1))) / ((3 * k) + 1))
        + (((a ** 4) * (d1 ** (4 * k + 1))) / ((4 * k) + 1))
        - (((a ** 5) * (d1 ** (5 * k + 1))) / ((5 * k) + 1))
    )
    b = D / C
    T = Tm + (Tc - Tm) * (b)
    EmT = (201.04 * (10) ** 9) * (
        1 + (3.079 * (10 ** (-4)) * T) - (6.534 * (10 ** (-7)) * (T ** 2))
    )

    EcT = (244.27 * (10) ** 9) * (
        1
        - (1.371 * (10 ** (-3)) * T)
        + (1.214 * (10 ** (-6)) * (T ** 2))
        - (3.681 * (10 ** (-10)) * (T ** 3))
    )
    VcT = (0.2882) * (1 + (1.133 * (10 ** (-4)) * T))

    VmT = (0.3262) * (
        1 - (2.002 * (10 ** (-4)) * T) + (3.797 * (10 ** (-7)) * (T ** 2))
    )
    Efg = (EcT - EmT) * ((d1) ** k) + EmT  # ((1.68e11-2.078e11)*((d1)**k) + 2.078e11)

    Vfg = (VcT - VmT) * ((d1) ** k) + VmT

    H = (4 * (Ro ** 2) - 2 * (z ** 2)) ** (0.5)

    L = (np.pi * y) / (2 * H)
    T = (y) / H
    M = (np.tan(L)) / L
    N1 = (1 - np.sin(L)) ** 4
    P = np.cos(L)
    F2 = ((M ** (0.5)) * (0.923 + 0.199 * (N1))) / P
    Q = Ro ** 2 - z ** 2
    S = (Ess) / (((Ro) ** 5) * Efg)

    return (16 * ((2) ** 0.5) * y * Q * (F2 ** 2)) * S


def bounds_z():
    return [0, B]


def bounds_y(z):
    return [0, ((a - Ro) + ((Ro ** 2 - 0.5 * (z ** 2))) ** 0.5)]


x4 = nquad(Cc55, [bounds_y, bounds_z])
print(x4[0])
```

```
C:\Users\arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
C:\Users\arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
C:\Users\arnab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:385: IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error is detected
  in the extrapolation table.  It is assumed that the requested tolerance
  cannot be achieved, and that the returned result (if full_output = 1) is 
  the best which can be obtained.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
```

Comment: Are you sure you coded the function correctly? I've checked the values it returns and it turns out that tiny changes in input cause huge changes in output. If that is the case, then no surprise you're getting such warnings.

Comment: Yes, the code is correct (excluding the error message). The parameters am interested to change are k and Tc, For example, if you set k=0.5, Tc=300, the results come without error.

Comment: In that case you have to use a different integration method to get reliable result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you suggest any other integration method to carry out the following integration? What procedure should I follow to do the same?

Comment: This is an overcomplicated example. Before posting code examples to stackoverflow, make sure they are _minimal_ and still reproduce the error. This way, people are more likely to help you. Also, minimizing the code is often a good step towards fixing the issue itself.

Comment: Try plotting the function in the interval of interest